# universal app with localization - splash screen

Tags: ios, localization, universal, splash-screen

I have a universal app with some localization. My problem is about splash screens.

I need 6 splash screens. 
iPad, iPhone, iPhoneRetina (in English) and  iPad, iPhone, iPhoneRetina (in Local Lang)

I have a file for iPad English Splash, named "Default.png". When I select this file on project navigator, I can add localized version by clicking "+" sign. As a result I have 2 files: Default.png (English) and Default.png (Local Lang)
So far eveything is ok.

But when I try to add "Default~iphone.png" file to the project, it doesn't get localized. XCode crashes when I click on the "+" sign.

What is the proper way of adding 6 (3 devices x 2 languages) splash screens to the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add them without XCode crash, you can use that trick :

Close your project. Go into your project folder into the Finder, create (if they are not already there) yourself the en.lproj, es.lproj, ... folders needed at the right place, and put your localized images inside them.

Then open your project, go to the project info panel, remove all possible localizations (keeping the files when asked), then add those localizations back (still in the project properties).

Then they will be shown like a charm in the file explorer tree.

Comment: I haven't tried, but probably would work. So I accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: Default.png has to be placed at the root of project folder. It will compile but it won't work if submitting to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export localized images from your image editor with exactly the same names as the English. Then drag and drop these files into the de.lproj group in Xcode.

The process altogether:

- Open Photoshop, export your 3 English .pngs
- Edit the PSD with your localized text
- Export the 3 localized .pngs with *exactly the same name*
- Drag and drop them into the local-lang.lproj grouping/folder in
  Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I realized that although XCode crashes, it somehow adds the localized splash screen images to the project.

I just kept repeating the procedure and let xcode crash each time. Finally I got what I needed.