# Default Splash Screen fails to get with region format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, localization

Here the problem is:

I have created "en.lproj" and "en-AU.lproj" with Different Default.png images with the same name.
I have set "English" as a language and for locale i have set "Australia".

But On launch i am getting Splash Screen referenced to "en.lproj" folder.

I need to get Splash Screen referenced to "en-AU.lproj" folder.

PS: I have checked my code , everything is correct with respect to setting or getting the UserDefaults.

Any Idea?

Comment: Can you plz explain "Different Default.png images with the same name"??

Comment: I mean , i am having Default.png in every localized folder but those Default.png images are different with same name as "Default.png".

Got it now?

Comment: Plz see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079563/universal-app-with-localization-splash-screen

Comment: Shouldn't it be en_AU (with an underscore) instead of en-AU.

Comment: @Frank: I tried that also . it doesn't work

Comment: hey neelam try this....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9411308/ios-launch-image-multiple-language

Comment: Just checking... Have you configured your project so that it supports en-AU as a localization? Having an lproj folder isn't enough, it needs to be listed in your info.plist as well (XCode does this automatically when you click + under languages)

Comment: Check your XCode project settings. Select your project (not target), go to Info and check if "English--Australia" is within the "Localizations" view. Also check if at least "1 File Localized" is within the same row otherwise it did not recognize your Default.png for this localization.

Comment: hey dude @CLafou ,anka .. have done this .. this doesn't solve my problem, At your end is it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something i found here:

**Important In iOS:** The bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in Mac OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories.

Referenced to :
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LanguageDesignations.html

I have to hack my code someway around , making Splash Screen appearance to be customized for different localized folder having Region Designator (ex: en-AU).

Thanks. :)